# Find when and where the user dropped off

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets assume that we have database that logs when a user is on a particular page. When a user does some action we log that. And when a user finishes an action on a page(screen) we log done.

Only when a user has finished with a particular page he will be able to go to another page. So we need to find out all the people who have not gone to the next screen. There are limited number of screens.

Can this be done with one single query?

I have tried to do this for each screen using this query:

```
select uid from logs where screenid=1 and uid not in (
select uid from logs where act='done' and screenid=1);
```

I am able to find people who got stuck for a particular screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I went over a couple more stackoverflow questions and found out

```
select * from logs as log1 right join(
select max(logtime) as maxLogTime, uid
from logs
group by uid ) as log2
on log2.uid = log1.uid and
log1.logTime = log2.maxLogTime;
```

is query for the solution.

One could also try this(Not a good technique):

```
select * from (
select * from logs 
order by logtime desc) as logDesc 
group by logDesc.uid;
```